# OpenCv: How to do background remover?

Tags: c++, opencv, background, foreground, subtraction

Basicly i need to cut foreground object from green screen video. I need to make green transparent or directly cut the foreground object. I need to use OpenCv and C++. I find couple of methods but doesnt work. What i need to do it?

Answer (score 1):

there isn't a magical way to do so. You need to programatically select the roi applying effects on each frame (i.e. on the `Mat` object). You may need to reduce noise, apply blur, extract each channels and do much more. So be patient and start experimenting.